# Very basic Clarke transform question

Tags: power, motor

So the process is to decompose the three phase vectors into two components Alpha and Beta (Im following the procedure on Openelectrical):

[image]

And the decomposition is done as follows:

[image]

When I do it myself, for U_Beta I get
        U_beta = Ua.Cos(pi/2)-Ub.Cos(pi/6)+Uc.Cos(pi/6)

Basically I get the signs for the last two terms for U_beta reversed.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where did you get those equations for Clarke transform? The trigonometric function come to play when you have a space vector known, else if you have components a,b,c then there is only multiplication and  summing.

Comment: I got it from here: http://www.openelectrical.org/wiki/index.php?title=Clarke_Transform

Has it got something to do with the Beta axis being labelled as jBeta?

Comment: Exactly, then you should learn to interpret the matrix equations in right way, because what you wrote is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

That image is reversed, "Uc" was swaped by "Ub" in that picture, so you are actually doing nothing wrong, your formula for "U_beta" is correct if you follow that picture.

The first decomposition that you showed is for the phasors in the left:

[image]

Comment: Has it got something to do with the vertical axis being labelled as jBeta instead of Beta?

Comment: No no, it just has to do with the fact that the "b" in this picture and the "b" in your picture are in different places.

Comment: I've edited my answer so that the differences in positioning of the "b" phasor should be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{bmatrix} U_{\alpha} \\ U_{\beta}  \\ \end{bmatrix}={\frac  23}{\begin{bmatrix}1&-{\frac  12}&-{\frac  12}\\0&{\frac  {{\sqrt  {3}}}{2}}&-{\frac  {{\sqrt  {3}}}{2}}\end{bmatrix}}{\begin{bmatrix}U_{a}(t)\\U_{b}(t)\\U_{c}(t)\end{bmatrix}}$$

EDIT:

I see now, your angles are constant, so the equation is the same one. You gave me a good idea: Next time someone will ask money from me, I should say: "Sorry, I have \$cos\dfrac{\pi}{2}\$ dollars in my pocket."